# Monotouch Events

Tags: c#, ios, events, xamarin.ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to run the following code with MonoTouch:

```
this.TouchesBegan += delegate { txtAmount.ResignFirstResponder(); };
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign to `TouchesBegan' because it is a `method group'
```

The API seems to support this: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/api_design

Any ideas?

Comment: In addition to poupou's answer, if you want to use the TouchesBegan method, you will have to subclass UIView (or whichever class' TouchesBegan method you want to use) and override it.

Comment: Turns out UIViewController also exposes the same method, so I simply overrode it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using `UIGestureRecognizer` right ?

If so then `TouchesBegan' is a **method** not an **event** so you cannot assign a delegate to it.

```
    public virtual void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
```

You might want to look at:

```
    public UITouchEventArgs ShouldReceiveTouch;
    public UIGesturesProbe ShouldRecognizeSimultaneously;
    public UIGestureProbe ShouldBegin;
```

and the [Touches_GestureRecognizers](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/Touches_GestureRecognizers) sample.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that.  Thanks!